# Cooling of a Uniform Sphere with Convective heat loss at the boundary

Tags: thermodynamics

What mathematical techniques can be used to find the evolution of the temperature of a uniform sphere if it is subject to convective cooling at its surface?  Are these techniques different from the case of conductive cooling?

[image: Cooling sphere]

For concreteness, assume the initial, uniform temperature to be $T_0$ and the surrounding temperature to be $T_e$. Radius is $R$.

Comment: I have attempted to edit the question to focus it more on the mathematical techniques involved, rather than seeming like a homework problem (in the hopes that it can then be reopened.)  Feel free to roll the edits back if this conflicts with your intent.

Comment: Thank you, Michael.

Answer (score 4):

What mathematical approach is preferred depends primarily on the Biot number $\text{Bi}$ of the system:

$$\text{Bi}=\frac{hR}{k}$$
where $h$ is the convective heat transfer coefficient, $k$ the thermal conductivity of the sphere's material and $R$ the sphere's radius.

1. High $\text{Bi}$ number:

This means the heat loss proceeds primarily by convection and that temperature gradients inside the sphere are small:

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial r} \approx 0$$

It also means that lumped thermal analysis can be applied here. We can use Newton's Law of Cooling:

$$-mc_p\frac{\text{d}T(t)}{\text{d}t}=hA[T(t)-T_e]\tag{1}$$

with $T_e$ the environment's temperature (far away from the sphere's surface)

$(1)$ is an ODE with separation of vaiables and is easy to solve.

2. Low $\text{Bi}$ number:

Here conduction prevails over convection and significant temperature gradients inside the sphere exist:

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial r} < 0$$

Lumped thermal analysis is likely to cause significant error here and we need to use Fourier's Heat Equation.

Define $u(r,t)=T(r,t)-T_e$, so that with Fourier for a sphere:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\alpha}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\Big(r^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\Big)$$
Make a subsitution:
$$v(r,t)=u(r,t)r$$
We obtain:
$$v_t=\alpha v_{rr}\tag{1}$$
BCs:

$$v_r(0,t)=0$$

BC from convection:
$$-ku_r(R,t)=hu(R,t)$$
Transcribed:
$$-kv_r(R,t)=\Big(h-\frac{k}{R}\Big)v(R,t)\tag{2}$$

Initial condition:
$$v(r,0)=(T_0-T_e)r$$
Going back to $(1)$:

$$v_t=\alpha v_{rr}\tag{1}$$

Using Ansatz and separation:

$$v(x,t)=R(r)\Theta(t)$$
allow determining $v(r)$ and thus $u(r)$.