# Is this how a sphere warms up?

Tags: thermodynamics, astrophysics

I have been trying to solve the heat equation for a uniform sphere. My setup: sphere has an initial temperature distribution, and the surface is kept at constant temperature. I am interested in how the temperature changes within the sphere over time. The below video is the visualisation of my results.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHOTqQI7LP8

Does it look realistic? Any feature on it which is an idication that I have messed it up?

Comment: This problem has an analytic solution. It is a commonly assigned as homework. I haven’t watched your video, but if you have done a numerical solution, then you can compare it against the analytic solution.

Comment: Your video looks about right.

Comment: It would be better to include your derivation or methodology, which for constant surface temperature isn't really that hard. Here's a derivation for heat loss (or gain, of course) with convection at the boundary: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/573910/cooling-of-a-uniform-sphere-with-convective-heat-loss-at-the-boundary/573911#573911

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes it does. Numerical methods used?

Comment: I describe my method here: http://ps738.user.srcf.net/planet.html. Ok, I'll update my question with these steps.